# How can I change the code of an imported package

Tags: python, import, package

I want to skip one line of code of a package that I import, without actually changing the code of the package itself. So is there a way in which I can manipulate the imported package in my own code?

Comment: you could override the method, but you might have to copy the required lines of code into the new custom built function.